# navigation.navigate is not working in Action sheet of Native Base

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, navigation, native-base

> i want to navigate to other screen but when i used onPress function it
> didn't work  on other screen it do work but in Native base Action
> sheet i didn't work
>
> this is my code

```
  const {
    isOpen,
    onOpen,
    onClose
  } = useDisclose();
```

> code of Native base Action sheet

```
<Actionsheet isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} size="full">
        <Actionsheet.Content>
      
         
            <Actionsheet.Item onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Drawer')}
              startIcon={<Icon as={<MaterialIcons name="share" />} color="muted.500" mr={3} />}>
              Test 1
            </Actionsheet.Item>
         
          <Actionsheet.Item startIcon={<Icon as={<MaterialCommunityIcons name="link" />} color="muted.500" mr={3} />}>
            Test 2
          </Actionsheet.Item>
          <Actionsheet.Item startIcon={<Icon as={<MaterialIcons name="edit" />} color="muted.500" mr={3} />}>
            Test 3
          </Actionsheet.Item>
          <Actionsheet.Item startIcon={<Icon as={<MaterialIcons name="delete" />} color="muted.500" mr={3} />}>
            Test 4
          </Actionsheet.Item>
        </Actionsheet.Content>
      </Actionsheet>
```

> export my screen code

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>

      <MyCurrentScreen  />

    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};
```

> this is error i got when i Press on Actionsheet.Item on my mobile

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
```

Comment: you have to pass navigation as prop from the parent screen where action sheet is called.

Answer (score 1):

In the component using navigation :

```
  import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
        
        function YourComponent() {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        
      return (
        ...
     )
```

}